# how would I make a jQuery dialog popup a specific number of times?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how would I determine the number of times a dialog should show in jQuery.
I have a modal popup dialog and I want when a user clicks on something 2 times the dialog shows and upon the third click it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#something_to_clicked').click(function(){

          $('#dialog_content').dialog({modal: true});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attach this to the dialog itself using `.data()` as such:

```
$('#dialog_content').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
}).data('timesShown', 0);

$('#something_to_clicked').click(function() {
    var myt = $('#dialog_content');
    if (myt.data('timesShown') < 2) {
        $('#dialog_content').data('timesShown', (1 + myt.data('timesShown')));
        myt.text(myt.text() + myt.data('timesShown')); //just to show
        myt.dialog("open");
    };
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZY795/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var timesShown = 0;
    $('#something_to_clicked').click(function(){
          if (timesShown == 2) return;
          $('#dialog_content').dialog({modal: true});
          timesShown++
    });
});
```